# Convert dynamic object to IEnumerable Issue

Tags: c#, .net, oop

```
protected override IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData()
{
    var request = new RestRequest();
    var directoryResponse = client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request).Result;

    dynamic directory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDTO>(directoryResponse.Content);

    cachedDirectory = directory;
}

return cachedDirectory;
```

Issue is on the line

```
cachedDirectory = directory;
```

Whenever it tries convert the `dynamic` object to an `IEnumerable` type.

Exception message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyDTO' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What is `directoryResponse.Content`? And why are you returning `IEnumerable<dynamic>` instead of the model?

Comment: So what is the type of `cachedDirectory`? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here, or what `MyDTO` is. (Also, your code has an extra close brace which makes it hard to understand.) Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am returning because it's an interface function which I have to override and I cannot change the return type of the function as it's part of the project. directoryResponse.Content is JsonArray

Comment: @DaisyShipton private IEnumerable<dynamic> cachedDirectory; in the rest request response i get some data and MyDTO have the fields which i parse through it.

Comment: If you need more concrete answer then please provide more detail as suggested by Daisy Shipton ? Like How MyDTO look like , directoryResponse.Content sample etc.

Comment: See my final edit.

Comment: Fundamentally, you're fetching a single MyDTO, and you want to return an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. What should that return value contain? How do you *expect* a `MyDTO` to be converted into an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`? Do you actually just want to create a sequence with that single entry in, or does the DTO contain a sequence of items?

Comment: @Daisy Shipton I have suggested same thing in my answer and even what I recognize from issue is that One side normal type and another side Enumerable but I feel that somebody in hurry to down vote.

Comment: @dotnetstep: I didn't downvote, but I don't think this question is clear enough to provide a meaningful answer to at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have to make few assumption.

- I assume that your cachedDirectory object is type of IEnumerable. If this is the case then it is clear that it can not convert MyDTO object to IEnumerable at runtime and it throw exception.

Following code give you error. I assume that you need enumrable.

```
    public class NewTest
    {
        IEnumerable<dynamic> cachedDirectory;
        public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData()
        {
            dynamic directory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDTO>("{ 'Name' : 'Test'  }");
            cachedDirectory = directory;
            return cachedDirectory;            
        }
    }

    public class MyDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

// This is how you call. (This code give error)

```
    NewTest test = new NewTest();
    IEnumerable<dynamic> result = test.GetData();
```

**Answer : If above is the way you use then you can do something like this.**

```
public class NewTest
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> cachedDirectory;
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetData()
    {
         var request = new RestRequest();
        var directoryResponse = client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request).Result;
        dynamic directory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEumerable<MyDTO>>(directoryResponse.Content);            
        return directory;            
    }
}

public class MyDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

// Now this will work.

```
    NewTest test = new NewTest();
    IEnumerable<dynamic> result = test.GetData();
```

Comment: Neither is it clear that the conversion is not possible (`MyDTO` might implement `IEnumerable`; the error message explicitly states that there is an explicit conversion), nor does this answer the question.

Comment: @dotnetstep you are right. But how I can resolve this?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I helpless to do this. At this point of time, i have searched a lot and not able to implement. Hope you can help me out with this.

Comment: @HimanshuChawla If you address the comments under your question, your chances of getting an answer will increase significantly.